# C# Error CS1061: 'PlayerInput.OnFootActions' does not contain a definition for 'look' and no accessible extension method 'look'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[InputManager Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNJlK.png)
[PlayerLook Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pwr5.png)

I'm getting an Error telling me that  'PlayerInput.OnFootActions' does not contain a definition for 'look' and no accessible extension method 'look' accepting a first argument of type 'PlayerInput.OnFootActions' could be found.(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have no idea why this is happening.

I'm fairly new to coding, so I don't know why this is happening, even though it look fine. Thank you for the help!

I've attempted delete the files and rewriting the code, but to no avail. I kept getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Does PlayerInput.OnFootAction have a member of type PlayerLook?
Knowing zero of what your are doing, it seems that the call

```
look.processLook(onFoot.look.ReadValue<Vector2>());
```

has something strange in the part onFoot.look. This is giving you a compilation error.

The compiler is looking for something called look into the type OnFootAction. And that seems visibly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the tutorial correctly, then it’s not `onFoot.look.ReadValue`, it’s supposed to be `onFoot.Look.ReadValue`. Note the capital ‘L’ in “Look”. I believe it’s the tutorial by Natty Creations. When following tutorials, you need to make sure spelling and capitalisation are observed.